# Photoshop Multiple Artboards Combine to Single Artboard?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How do you combine multiple artboards into the same artboard or canvas?

(Other than painfully and manually dragging...)

Comment: Which version of Photoshop are you using?

Answer (score 0):

- In the Layers panel, select all the artboards that you want to combine.
- Right click and select 'Ungroup Artboards'. This removes the artboards and reveals the total canvas size.
- If you want to re combine them into a single artboard, select all the layers and right click and select, 'Artboard from Layers'.